# Android - Drawable filter color on alpha channel

Tags: android, colors, drawable, alpha

I got some Drawables from Android resources and I want to change their colors and alpha channel to solid (The images have opacity). I tried to use `setFilterColor` but it just changes the color and the alpha channel is still half transparent. How can I change the opacity too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the class [`ColorMatrixColorFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html)